# run method after jquery confimation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, function

How would I run a method in backend to send emails when I have a jquery dialogue with yes and no button as following :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true
            });
        });

        $(".confirmLink").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close"),
                        SendEmail(),
                    window.location.href = targetUrl;
                    },
                    "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    </script>

<a class="confirmLink" href="emailsend.aspx"></a>
     <div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
                    <p>
                        Do you want to send an email?</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to communicate this with the back end via ajax, the backend would then send the email; a little like this:

```
function SendEmail(email, content)
{
    var data = "email=" + escape(email) + "&content=" + escape(content);
    $.ajax({
        url: "sendemail.asp",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            alert("Hurray");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Oh noes! It went wrong");
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `data` can be a javascript object `{email:'a@b.c',content:'aaa'}`, you don't have to manually serialize and escape it.